# Outook. Delete Email

Tags: outlook

Is there a way where I can delete all the emails from a folder at a set time everyday when AutoArchive is disable on my system ? Typically I would use AutoArchive to resolve this but currently it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a daily recurring task, with a reminder and a unique subject.

In the ThisOutlookSession module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

    If Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Task" Then

        If Item.Subject = "Scheduled Deletion" Then
            DeleteFromToBeDeleted
        End If

    End If

End Sub


Sub DeleteFromToBeDeleted()

    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim i As Long

    Set myFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"). _
            GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ToBeDeleted")

    For i = myFolder.items.Count To 1 Step -1
        myFolder.items(i).Delete
    Next i

    Set myFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```